# Align center Textview in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I'm making an interface like this, I want to help layout pink area. This is the result I want. [image: http://i.imgur.com/MnkuZGZ.pn]

I tried but not success. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kilobolt.robotgame.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/Heading">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/PrevMonth" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShowDay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_date"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/welcome_nam"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is interface after that:

[image]

Comment: try to use seperate linear layout for textview and make that linear layout center it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this with weight property in LinearLayout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```